# Calculus Optimization circle and square

Tags: calculus, optimization

Six feet of wire is used to form a square and a circle.  How much of the wire should be used for the square and how much should be used for the circle to enclose the maximum total area?

What is this question asking me to find?

Answer (score 0):

It's asking you to find the maximum sum of the areas of a square and a circle, provided that the sum of their perimeters is six feet, and to describe for such cofigurations how long the perimeter of the square and the circumference are.